# Debugging PXE boot issues

Tags: uefi, pxe

I am trying to set up a PXE boot server and the client boot is failing and dropping into the UEFI interactive shell.
The system is Rocky Linux (RHEL8).
I have copied the grub2 and shimx64.efi files into the uefi path and set up the dhcp server for network book and provided uefi/shimx64.efi for the UEFI 64-bit filename.
I know that the PXE server is working because when I try legacy BIOS it executes the menu defined in pxelinux.cfg/default - so I am confident that the DHCP infrastructure is correct and TFTP is working.

So I cannot work out why the uefi boot will not load the shims. Is there a way to dump tftp logs and see what files are trying to be pulled from the server?

Comment: Turning on tftp logging will depend on what tftp server you have. If the tftp server is persistent then you can probably use `strace -f -p 12345` where 12345 is the PID of the trtpd to get some strong hints about what it is looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately tftp is run by systemd so I have no process to attach to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the log location for tftp.

> tail -f /var/log/messages

This displays all the useful information for debugging what is going on with a PXE server.